# python quickly get index of elements in bigger list which also exists in a smaller list

Tags: python, list, performance

I have two lists A and B, and list B is a subset of list A

For example,

```
A = ['andy', 'john', 'frank', 'max', 'julia']

B = ['andy', 'max', 'julia']
```

and the desired output is the index of list A for shared elements, which is in this case,

```
C = [0, 3, 4]
```

The method I come up with is using two for loops, and it looks like:

```
C = []

for bb in B:
   for aa in A:
      if bb == aa:
         C.append(A.index(aa))
```

However, above method seems quite inefficient, and it becomes quite a problem since size of both A and B is quite big in my real application, and I have to do this process repeatedly.

Any idea on how to make this faster? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `list comprehension`:

```
>>> A = ['andy', 'john', 'frank', 'max', 'julia']
>>> B = ['andy', 'max', 'julia']
>>> [i for i,v in enumerate(A) if v in B]
[0, 3, 4]
>>> ]
```

Or a more efficient and shorter `list comprehension`:

```
>>> [A.index(i) for i in B]
[0, 3, 4]
>>>
```

As mentioned by @Matthias's comment you could do the below for the first code example:

```
[i for i,v in enumerate(A) if v in set(B)]
```

To make it faster, but also depends of size of list too as @Matthias additionally says.

Comment: Beautiful. This made the computation time about 10 folds less in my real application. Thank you very much!! :)

Comment: @H.Choi Happy to help, :-), 

Comment: Additionally you could try to convert `B` to a `set`. Lookup in a set is much faster than a lookup in a list.

Comment: Both of these approaches are O(AB) - you can get O(A) with `[i for i,v in enumerate(A) if v in set(B)]`

Comment: Of course it depends on the size of the lists. Converting the list to a set takes some time too.

Comment: Converting the list to a set is O(B), so the entire complexity is O(A+B) which reduces to O(A)

Comment: @Matthias & ic3b3rg
I converted the size of the list to run some tests, and it appears in some cases set approach is better. I'll keep that in mind. Thank you !